# Create pdf with WKWebView.pdf(configuration:)

Tags: swift, apple-pdfkit

I want to create a pdf on macOS with the new `WKWebView.pdf(configuration:)` which was introduced in macOS 12/iOS 15. It tries to make use of the new async/await functionality (which I most likely have not grasped entirely I am afraid...).

Right now, I am getting an error that I have no idea how to handle:

```
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=1 "An unknown error occurred" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred}
```

I try to load a html string into a web view, which I then want to generate the pdf from. The function I use to generate my `PDFDocument` looks like this:

```swift
func generatePdf() async {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        await webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
        
        let config = WKPDFConfiguration()
        config.rect = .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 595.28, height: 841.89))
        do {
            //this is where the error is happening
            let pdfData = try await webView.pdf(configuration: config)
            self.pdf = PDFDocument(data: pdfData)
        } catch {
            print(error) //this error gets printed
        }
    }
```

My best guess as it currently stands is that `WKWebView`'s `loadHTMLString` has not finished loading the html–I did allow for outgoing connection in the app sandbox that's not it...

For the sake of completeness, here's the entire code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit
import WebKit

@main
struct AFPdfApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $vm.html)
                .frame(width: 300.0, height: 200.0)
                .border(Color.accentColor, width: 1.0)
                .padding()
            PdfViewWrapper(pdfDocument: $vm.pdf)
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("Create PDF") {
                Task {
                    await vm.generatePdf()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    static let initHtml = """
    <h1>Some fancy html</h1>
    <h2>…and now how do I create a pdf from this?</h2>
    """
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var html = """
    <h1>Some fancy html</h1>
    <h2>…and now let's create some pdf…</h2>
    """
    @Published var pdf: PDFDocument? = nil
    
    func generatePdf() async {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        await webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
        
        let config = WKPDFConfiguration()
        config.rect = .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 595.28, height: 841.89))
        do {
            let pdfData = try await webView.pdf(configuration: config)
            self.pdf = PDFDocument(data: pdfData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

struct PdfViewWrapper: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var pdfDocument: PDFDocument?
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        return PDFView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: PDFView, context: Context) {
        nsView.document = pdfDocument
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. I'm also trying various ways to show a PDF from a WKWebview's HTML. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am afraid I have not–to be quite honest, I also have not taken another good look at it. Not having anyone answer here kind of shows that there does not seem to be a too easy solution...

Comment: So I have actually had a little success last night. I use an invisible WKWebView in a button handler to generate HTML, then assign a delegate, which checks for document.readyState by evaluating JavaScript and only generates PDF once ready. I will try to post an answer later. Unfortunately, the generated PDF is not paginated, so it results in a potentially long single page document.

Comment: Interesting, I am looking forward to seeing your code on that. In the meantime, I took another look at it and (kind of) found a solution–see my new answer below on my current state.

Comment: Seems like I have reached that point before... 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997361/swift-create-pdf-with-wkwebviews-createpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997361/swift-create-pdf-with-wkwebviews-createpdf)

Comment: So yes–in the end what's left for us to do is pagination (which is available in UIKit-land but not in AppKit-land…)

Answer (score 4):

After Chris made me take another look at it (thanks for that :-) ) I am now a step closer to a working solution.

It really seems as though I really have to wait for the webView to load the html prior to creating the pdf. While I was not able to make it work with `WKWebView.pdf(configuration:)`, I now have a (kind of…) working solution by using `WKWebView.createPDF(configuration:completionHandler:)`:

```swift
    func generatePdf() {
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            let config = WKPDFConfiguration()
            config.rect = .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 595.28, height: 841.89))
            self.webView.createPDF(configuration: config){ result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let data):
                    self.pdf = PDFDocument(data: data)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I said "kind of works" above, because the resulting pdf seems to introduce a new line after each word, which is weird–but I will scope that issue to another research/question on SO.

Again, for the sake of completeness, here's the whole "app":

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit
import WebKit

@main
struct AFPdfApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

//MARK: View
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $vm.htmlString)
                .frame(width: 300.0, height: 200.0)
                .border(Color.accentColor, width: 1.0)
                .padding()
            WebViewWrapper(htmlString: $vm.htmlString)
            PdfViewRepresentable(pdfDocument: $vm.pdf)
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("Create PDF") {
                Task {
                    vm.generatePdf()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//MARK: ViewModel
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var htmlString = """
    <h1>Some fancy html</h1>
    <h2>…and now let's create some pdf…</h2>
    """
    @Published var webView = WKWebView()
    @Published var pdf: PDFDocument? = nil
    
    func generatePdf() {
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            let config = WKPDFConfiguration()
            config.rect = .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 595.28, height: 841.89))
            self.webView.createPDF(configuration: config){ result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let data):
                    self.pdf = PDFDocument(data: data)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//MARK: ViewRepresentables
struct WebViewWrapper: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var htmlString: String
    
    public func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    public func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        nsView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
    }
}

struct PdfViewRepresentable: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var pdfDocument: PDFDocument?
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        return PDFView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: PDFView, context: Context) {
        nsView.document = pdfDocument
    }
}
```

Comment: is this working nicely for you now?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that I got this working. It uses a completely hidden `WKWebView` to render the content, using a delegate callback and javascript execution to determine when the page has fully loaded.

When ready, the new iOS 15 `WKWebView` method `.pdf()` is called, which generates the PDF data.

Bindings are used to update the parent view, which generates a `PDFDocument` from the data and navigates to it.

Caveat: The native `WKWebView` PDF methods do not produce paginated PDF files, so it will be one long page!

---

In the main view it starts with a button tap. This view has a `pdfData` variable that is of type `Data` and will be used to make the PDF document.

```
Button("Generate PDF") {

    // Prevent triggering again while already processing
    guard !isWorking else { return }
    
    // Reset flags
    isReadyToRenderPDF = false
    isWorking = true

    // Initialise webView with frame equal to A4 paper size in points
    // (I also tried UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 595, height: 842))) // A4 size     

    // Set web view navigation delegate.
    // You must keep a strong reference to this, so I made it an @State property on this view
    // This is a class that takes bindings so it can update the data and signal completion
    self.navigationDelegate = WKWebViewDelegate(wkWebView!, pdfData: $data, isReadyToRenderPDF: $isReadyToRenderPDF)
    wkWebView!.navigationDelegate = self.navigationDelegate
        
    // Generate HTML. You could also use a simple HTML string.
    // This is just my implementation.
    let htmlContent = htmlComposer.makeHTMLString()
    
    // Load HTML into web view
    wkWebView!.loadHTMLString(htmlContent, baseURL: nil)
    
    // Now the navigation delegate responds when data is updated.
}
```

The WKWebView delegate class has this callback method.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    // This ensures following code only runs once, as delegate method is called multiple times.
    guard !readyOnce else { return }
    
    // Use javascript to check document ready state (all images and resources loaded)
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState == \"complete\"") { result, error in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else if result as? Int == 1 {
            self.readyOnce = true
            do {
                // Create PDF using WKWebView method and assign it to the binding (updates data variable in main view)
                self.pdfData = try await webView.pdf()
                
                // Signal to parent view via binding
                self.isReadyToRenderPDF = true
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Back in parent view, respond to the change of Boolean value.

```
.onChange(of: isReadyToRenderPDF) { _ in
    isWorking = false
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // This toggle navigation link or sheet displaying PDF View using pdfData variable
            isShowingPDFView = true
        }
}
```

Finally, here is a `PDFKit` `PDFView` wrapped in `UIViewRepresentable`.

```
import SwiftUI
import PDFKit

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let data: Data
    
    init(_ data: Data) {
        self.data = data
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        // Create PDFKit view and document
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displaysPageBreaks = true
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        // Not implemented
    }
}
```